# Querying Proliant servers for NIC firmware version

Tags: hp, hp-proliant

I need to query a whole bunch of Proliant servers for the firmware version on their NICs.  I know I can find this information through HP Insight Management page, but the sheer number I need to check makes this a daunting task.  Anyone know of a way to get this information remotely through WMI or some other service or tool?  I've combed the Internet with no luck.

Thanks!

Comment: Windows-only? Or do you have Linux systems?

Comment: Yes, Windows only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use "hpdiscovery" in [HP SmartStart Scripting Toolkit](http://h18013.www1.hp.com/products/servers/management/toolkit/index.html). This tool generates clear xml where you can find section with network adapters.

For example:

```
<NetworkAdapters>
    <NetworkAdapter name="eth0">
        <MACAddress>xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx</MACAddress>
        <PCILocation>0000:02:00.0</PCILocation>
        <Firmware>1.5-9</Firmware>
        <PXEOrder>1</PXEOrder>
        <SlotNumber>0</SlotNumber>
    </NetworkAdapter>
    <!-- More adapters  -->
</NetworkAdapters>
```

**Edit:**
nowadays you can use RESTful API to retreive Firmware Inventory (Proliant gen9; iLO > 2.30). It's pretty simple, you just need to GET (with Basic auth. headers) `https://<iLO IP address>/rest/v1/Systems/1/FirmwareInventory`

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get that via HP's System Insight Manager (and upgrade them too if you like).

Comment: With SIM, I can get the firmware version for just about every piece of hardware in the server EXCEPT the NIC.  Don't know why.

Comment: That IS odd, hmmm... I'll do some digging.